# Update using join and group with count

Tags: mysql, join, updates

I am able to do an update between tables based on a count in the second table like so:

```
Update TableJ J
Inner Join (Select B_ID,C,S from TableC group by C,S having count=1) C
On J.C=C.C and J.S=C.S
Set T1.B_ID=T2.B_ID
```

The problem is my TableC does not contain `S`, that is stored in another table and related via `B` call it `Table_BS` (no jokes please :| ). If I didn't have to worry about count therefore I could do:

```
Update TableJ J
Inner Join TableC C
Inner Join TableBS BS
On J.C=C.C and C.S=BS.S
Set J.B_ID=BS.B_ID
```

Except the issue is, as with the original count, I only want to return `B_ID` when there is only one `C` record with an `S` record in `TableBS`.

Update:
Well this is how far I've gotten (select wise):

```
Select J.ID,B.B_ID
From DBJ J Inner Join LBS B Inner Join  C 
On J.C=C.C And (
J.S_ID = B.S_ID 
or J.S_ID=B.CS_ID) 
and B.B_ID=C.B_ID
```

Which in my case returns three records:

```
+----+------+
| ID | B_ID |
+----+------+
| 88 | 100  |
+----+------+
| 90 | 200  |
+----+------+
| 90 | 200  |
+----+------+
```

ID being the record I want to update, B_ID being the value I want to update with. In this case it turns out the count I am trying to limit is the ID column in the output, in other words I only want to update TableJ, record 88 with the value 100. TableJ record 90 turns out to have >1 result so I want to skip it. Just not sure where to put the `group by` or `count` here.

Update: Not sure why this solution remains just outside my grasp though getting closer, I can get the select to now return the ID of the record to update and the value to update with only on those records with one result like so:

```
Select J.ID,B.B_ID
From DBJ J Inner Join LBS B Inner Join  C 
On J.C=C.C And (
J.S_ID = B.S_ID 
or J.S_ID=B.CS_ID) 
and B.B_ID=C.B_ID group by J.ID having count(*)=1
```

which returns

```
+----+------+
| ID | B_ID |
+----+------+
| 88 | 100  |
+----+------+
```

And still unable to now get that to update TableJ record 88 field B_ID with the value of 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have done the trick so far:

```
Update TableJ T1
Inner Join
(Select J.ID,B.B_ID
From TableJ J Inner Join TableBS B Inner Join  TableC C
On J.C=C.C 
And J.S = B.S
And B.B_ID=C.B_ID 
group by J.ID having count(*)=1)  T2
On T1.ID=T2.ID Set T1.B_ID=T2.B_ID
```

Basically solved it first with a select that returned the ID of the Update TableJ and the B_ID from TableBS where the C in TableC matched the C in TableJ and the S in TableBS matched the S in TableJ.  I did a count on the results based on the ID in TableJ so that I only returned values when I got one result.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly the problem,but here is my solution

```
Update TableJ J 
Inner Join (
 Select B_ID,TableC.C, TableBS.S 
 from TableC Inner Join TableBS
 on TableC.B= TableBS.B 
 group by TableC.C,TableBS.S 
 having count(*)=1
) C 
On J.C=C.C 
Set J.B_ID=C.B_ID
```

Comment: Thanks but that updates extraneous records. The basic idea is there can be multiple records in TableC with records in TableBS but only one with value S. I've updated my answer as I close in on it above.